# Is it Possible to changes route on scroll (down / Up)

Tags: angular

I have an app using angular 4.

I need Changes route on when scroll.

Here is my code.

app.routing.module.ts

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/start', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'start', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'lazy', component: LazyComponent },
  { path: 'advanced', component: RestComponent },
  { path: 'basic', component: BasicComponent },
  { path: 'drilldown', component: DrilldownComponent },
  { path: 'styling', component: StylingComponent },
  { path: 'record-selection', component: RecordSelectionComponent },
  { path: 'totals', component: AggregateComponent },
  { path: 'custom-column', component: CustomColumnComponent },
  { path: 'column-click', component: ColumnClickComponent },
  { path: 'localization', component: LocalizationComponent },
  { path: 'inline-editing', component: InlineEditingComponent },
  { path: 'add-remove-edit', component: AddRemoveEditComponent },
  { path: 'column-settings-component', component: ChangeColumnSettingsComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a recommended feature but it is possible.
There are two ways I can think of to approach this.

1. I would write a directive which detects scroll events using the HostListener decorator, detect all scroll and if the delta of the scroll exceeds a certain value trigger a navigation. (I used the snippet below to collapse a navbar on scroll and I modified it for your request).

```javascript
@Directive({
  selector: '[navigateOnScroll]'
})
export class NavigateOnScrollDirective implements OnDestroy {
  didScroll: boolean;
  lastScrollTop: number;
  navbarHeight: number;
  delta: number = 5; // set any value you wnat here
  interval: any;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) // this sets the listener to the scroll event
  track() {
    this.didScroll = true;
  }
  constructor(private router: Router, // import router for navigation purposes
              private el: ElementRef) {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.didScroll) {
        this.hasScrolled();
        this.didScroll = false;
      }
    }, 250);
  }

  hasScrolled() {
    this.navbarHeight = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    const st = window.pageYOffset;
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if (Math.abs(this.lastScrollTop - st) <= this.delta) {
      return;
    }
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > this.lastScrollTop && st > this.navbarHeight) {
      // Scroll Down
      this.router.navigate(['/your', 'path', 'here']);
    } else {
      // Scroll Up
      this.router.navigate(['/your', 'path', 'here']);
    }
    this.lastScrollTop = st;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

*I followed this post while writing this and modified it for Angular 2+:
https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c

2. Write a directive that checks if the element which it was placed on is in the DOM and if so trigger the navigation. Use similar code but place the directive itself on an element that is under the fold. Then change to logic to test if the element offset from the bottom is larger than 0. Haven't tried this but this should work.

Hope this helps, good luck!